# How to prompt a modal that will ask the user whether he/she wants to delete the selected row or not? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am required to make a program that takes the input from a modal, and puts it into a table. Each row needs to have an edit and a delete icon (using FontAwesome). For the context of this question, i am focusing on the delete icon/button. Currently the delete icon needs to be a button that once pressed displays a modal asking the user whether he/she is sure that they want to delete the information in the row. The modal will contain two buttons giving the user the choice to take one of two actions, (Yes Button - Deletes the row and all of its contents; No Button - simply closes the modal). Below i have given the jQuery code (it needs to be written in jQuery), up until now, my code displays the icons as buttons, and once the delete icon/button is clicked, the row is deleted, but only then is the modal displayed. (currently the modal has no functionality, ie. Non of the buttons do anything).

jQuery:

```
function deleteData(btnDelete) {
  $(btnDelete).parents("tr").remove();
}

function openModal() {
  $('#modalDelete').show();
}

//function that adds input values to the table
function addToTable() {
  //add tbody tag if one is not present
  if($("#inputTable tBody").length == 0) {
    $("#inputTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
  }

  $(function() {
    $('#insertImage').on('change', function()
    {
      var filePath = $(this).val();
      console.log(filePath);
    });
  });

  //append inputs to the Table
  $("#inputTable tbody").append(
    "<tr>" +
      "<td>" +  + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + $("#addName").val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + $("#addSurname").val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
        "<button type='button' " +
          "class='btn'><i class='fas fa-user-edit' id='pencilIcon'></i></button>" +
      "<td>" +
        "<button type='button' " +
          "onclick='deleteData(this); openModal();'" +
          "class='btn'><i class='fas fa-dumpster' id='dumpsterIcon'></i></button>" +
        "</button>" +
      "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );


}

//add the inputed content to the table
$("#addToTable").click(function(){
  addToTable();
});
```

HTML (The table):

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="addDataToTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="website" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Data to Table</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="insertImage">Insert Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="InsertImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" aria-describedby="inputHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addSurname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addSurname">
              </div>
            </form>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addToTable">Add to Table</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

HTML (The Delete Modal):

```
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalDelete">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: for starters change this "onclick='deleteData(this); openModal();'" to "onclick='"openModal();'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a pure javascript solution:

```
var delete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");
if (delete ) { 
  //code to delete
}
```